# Cannot view files associated with specific label in Perforce P4V Linux client

Tags: linux, perforce, label, p4v

There is simply no option anywhere (and I've looked everywhere) to get a list of the files associated with a specific label in Perforce P4V on Linux.

I've seen a similar question that mentioned a menu button "List files at " but this does not exist so far as I can tell.

Is this simply absent in the Linux version?

There's a command line operation that will do this, `p4 files @<label>`. Is there a way I can have this executed within the client to display in the log window?  I just like having everything as grouped as possible.  Or can I create a "custom tool" that will open a terminal window and run this command?

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, I can do a `Search > Find File`, then use a `Raw Query` like `//dev/...@somelabel`.